# Format for decimal value

Tags: java, format, decimal

I need to validate a float variable for the decimal format check.
If the value is having 4 numbers before the decimal value (like 1234.12) print fail and if (123.12) it will pass.

Comment: `(""+1234.12).indexOf ('.')`

Comment: Is the number is float all the case?

Comment: @Bitz How does it relates to #selenium ? Thanks

Comment: @Bitz How does it relates to #xml ? Thanks

Comment: Its an example of 1234.12 I mean if the value consists of 4 numbers before decimal it will fail

Comment: I am importing an xml which is having an attribute value and need to check in the db if the value is like that it will fail.

Comment: I am a QA and I am creating a framework using Java Selenium

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying that the number has to contain less than 4 digits before the decimal meaning that you should do:

```
if(x < 1000){
   //*The number passes*
}else{
   //*The number isn't below 4 digits so it fails*
}
```

Comment: I think this does answer your question, you don't need a special parser to check if you have 4 digits before the decimal. If you really want to be weird about it you could do `if(Math.log(x) < 3){ //**Pass*// }`

Answer (score 0):

How about using StringTokenizer(delim ".") and check the length of String?

```
StringTokenizer parsing = new StringTokenizer("1234.12",".");
while(parsing.hasToken()) {
    String thisToken = parsing.nextToken().toString();
    if(thisToken.length() > 3) {
        // What ever you want
    }
}
```

Acutually, I am writing on phone, so, I cannot sure grammar error.

Comment: Its an example of 1234.12 I mean if the value consists of 4 numbers before decimal it will fail

Comment: Then how about t

Comment: could you please explain

Comment: Oh my god, I typed the whole things but suddenly blow up :(
Actually I cannot understand your words "if the value consists of 4 numbers before decimal it will fail".
I understand that 4 decimal = it will fail. That means that number should not over 1000. Then how about using Integer boxing?
`Integer.valueOf(thisToken).length() > 1000`

Comment: the attribute value can be a whole number like 234 or a flot like 234.12...if the value is 4567 or 3244.12 it will fail...means if there are more than 3 numbers in the left side of the point it will fail.

Comment: If you are loading number in `String`, Upper codes will work.
If you are loading numbers in `float` or `long`, You can make them to String temporarily by using `String.valueOf((float) variable)`

Comment: And if you are loading some attributes which was in XML, that will be loaded in `String` type. not number.